# Selenium C#: Not able to read value from textbox with "pre" html tag

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to read the text value from "Subject" field as mentioned below.

```
string settingsEmailSubject = iBrowserr.GetValue("//div[@class='sc-view sc-pane sc-panel sc-sheet settings-pane']/div/div[@class='sc-view sc-text-field-view subject-line allow-select']");
```

But, my code is returning null value. I am seeking your advice to solve this issue.

Notes:

Tried with `Webelement`, `driver.GetAttribute`, `driver.Selected.GetSelected` etc.

xpath:

```
//div[@class='sc-view sc-pane sc-panel sc-sheet settings-pane']/div/div[@class='sc-view sc-text-field-view subject-line allow-select']/pre[@contenteditable='true' is not working as well.
```

[image]

Comment: In java, we have getText() to get the text from element. Are we having something similar in c#.. Can you try like this ->driver.FindElement(By.Class("anketa_item-city")).Text;

Comment: Can you give the full HTML of the element?

Comment: Hi Monika. please refer my screen shot. It has complete details about the element. Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by selecting the parent element of the `pre` and then searching in the element for the `pre` element:

```
var parent_of_pre = iBrowserr.FindElement(By.XPath("xpath-got-from-chrome"))
var pre_element = parent_of_pre.FindElement(By.XPath("pre"))
string text_pre_element = pre_element.Text
```

Note that this will work only if the xpath is correct.

Comment: Hi Alex, I forgot to  update in my question. These 2 options are already tried. But no, luck :(!

Comment: Hi Alex, it says element is not found. Same logic works for other elements on the pop up. The main issue with "Subject" element is "pre" html tag.

Comment: Try to select the parent element of the `pre` and after that search in the element for pre using xpath: `var parent_pre = iBrowserr.FindElement(By.XPath("get-xpath-with-chrome"))` and after that `var pre_element = parent_pre.FindElement(By.XPath("pre"))`

Comment: Hi Alex, your solution is 100% perfect. Thanks a lot for your support!